# Image fields not switching with Drupal Image Replace module

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

I recently had a team member install the Image Replace module on a site we are working on for the purpose of having different versions of a hero image for both desktop and mobile resolutions. I followed all of the steps on [this blog](http://activelamp.com/blog/drupal/how-to-use-picture-and-image-replace-for-drupal-7/) as closely as I could- but even with the module activated, breakpoints created, image styles and picture mappings set, and the image fields edited to specify which field they are swapped with and at which breakpoints... no images are being replaced.

Just to offer any sort of potential clue, if I drag the image from a field that is intended to be swapped out at both breakpoints specified for the picture mapping into a new tab, the "correct" image styles are specified in the url but are not swapping the image as they are supposed to. In other words, I can look at the hero image at a mobile-intended breakpoint in a new tab and it will load the desktop version of the image but the url includes the string used for the mobile image style, which should mean the current image should be the swapped out mobile version as was specified in the "edit field" window during the setup process.

So, I'm very puzzled. If anyone can offer any advice it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Didn't use that module, but it's pretty easy to detect platform (is it desktop or mobile) so just have 2 images instead of one and print 1 of those 2 depending on platform. Do you really need a module for that?

Comment: Yeah it would be easy enough to do something similar with other methods but my understanding is that using the module would help the site work better in the backend. Plus its what the boss wants.